# I am getting error when i want to query to save multiple lines of MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

i am getting come error like

```
"Could not connect: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES (null, '206', 'asdas', 'asasdff', 'asdfasd', 'asdsdsad', 'asdasdf', 'qw' at line 1"
```

Code is here:

```
if($form_finished){
    // database info removed for posting here.
    $link = mysql_connect('******', '****', '*****');
        if (!$link) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
        mysql_select_db('listing');
            $query="";

    $spcats = explode(",", $fat_cats);  
    $query .= "INSERT INTO listings "; 

     for($k=0;$k<count($spcats)-1;$k++){
        $query .= " VALUES (null, '".$spcats[$k]."', '".$contact_fname."', '".$contact_lname."', '".$contact_email."', '".$contact_phone."', '".$listing_company_name_1."', '".$listing_phone_1."', '".$listing_address_1."', '".$listing_city_1."', '".$listing_state_1."', '".$listing_zip_1."', '".$listing_description_1."', '".$format_listing_urls."', '".$format_perimeters."'),"; 
    } 

    $query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query)-1) . ";";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
}
```

but when i use simple query, i will be saved in database.

**From Another way i done it by doing some changes:**

```
for($k=0;$k<count($spcats)-1;$k++){
        $query = "INSERT INTO listings  VALUES (null, '".$spcats[$k]."', '".$contact_fname."', '".$contact_lname."', '".$contact_email."', '".$contact_phone."', '".$listing_company_name_1."', '".$listing_phone_1."', '".$listing_address_1."', '".$listing_city_1."', '".$listing_state_1."', '".$listing_zip_1."', '".$listing_description_1."', '".$format_listing_urls."', '".$format_perimeters."');"; 
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());} else {print $spcats[$k]." is done.<br>";}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're inserting multiple values using a single INSERT statement you only need to specify the VALUES keyword once, so these lines

```
$query .= "INSERT INTO listings "; 

 for($k=0;$k<count($spcats)-1;$k++){
    $query .= " VALUES (null, '".$spcats[$k]."', '".$contact_fname."', '".$contact_lname."', '".$contact_email."', '".$contact_phone."', '".$listing_company_name_1."', '".$listing_phone_1."', '".$listing_address_1."', '".$listing_city_1."', '".$listing_state_1."', '".$listing_zip_1."', '".$listing_description_1."', '".$format_listing_urls."', '".$format_perimeters."'),"; 
}
```

Should be

```
$query .= "INSERT INTO listings VALUES "; 

 for($k=0;$k<count($spcats)-1;$k++){
    $query .= " (null, '".$spcats[$k]."', '".$contact_fname."', '".$contact_lname."', '".$contact_email."', '".$contact_phone."', '".$listing_company_name_1."', '".$listing_phone_1."', '".$listing_address_1."', '".$listing_city_1."', '".$listing_state_1."', '".$listing_zip_1."', '".$listing_description_1."', '".$format_listing_urls."', '".$format_perimeters."'),"; 
}
```

Comment: The hanging `,` at the end of the query will probably cause some issues

Comment: @jprofitt: $query = substr($query, 0, strlen($query)-1) . ";"; this code is removing last , also.

Comment: but if i copy the same generated code and pate into phpmyadmin and press the query button. all the data saves into the table. and the same generated code not working in my code's query process.

Comment: @jprofitt Yes, I thought that but the OP is removing the query, would be better to store all the inserts in an array and implode them.

Comment: @extremerose71 Have you tried debugging the script by echoing out the query when it fails?

Comment: @liquorvicar: yeh i tried every thing is ok. but i done it by another way.

Comment: @extremerose71 Having multiple values in an insert query is not the same as multiple queries. IIRC multiple values in one insert query will work fine in PHP.